# Is there a way to dynamically create an object at run time in .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I'm working on an importer that takes tab delimited text files. The first line of each file contains 'columns' like ItemCode, Language, ImportMode etc and there can be varying numbers of columns.

I'm able to get the names of each column, whether there's one or 10 and so on. I use a method to achieve this that returns `List<string>`:

```
private List<string> GetColumnNames(string saveLocation, int numColumns)
{
    var data = (File.ReadAllLines(saveLocation));
    var columnNames = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++)
    {
        var cols = from lines in data
        .Take(1)
        .Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
        .Select(l => l.Split(delimiter.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.None))
        .Select(value => string.Join(" ", value))
               let split = lines.Split(' ')
               select new
               {
                   Temp = split[i].Trim()
               };

        foreach (var x in cols)
        {
            columnNames.Add(x.Temp);
        }
    }
    return columnNames;
}
```

If I always knew what columns to be expecting, I could just create a new object, but since I don't, I'm wondering is there a way I can dynamically create an object with properties that correspond to whatever `GetColumnNames()` returns?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe [datatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) is meant for such cases.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable for more examples

Comment: If you would consider using >= .net4.0 you could use an ExpandoObject which is a *dynamic* object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx

Comment: I came across `ExpandoObject` but unfortunately what I'm on working on is 3.5.

Comment: Aren't you reading the entre file for each column? `ReadAllLines ()` is inside your `For` loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, here's how I used DataTables to achieve what I wanted.

```
// saveLocation is file location
// numColumns comes from another method that gets number of columns in file
var columnNames = GetColumnNames(saveLocation, numColumns);

var table = new DataTable();
foreach (var header in columnNames)
{
    table.Columns.Add(header);
}

// itemAttributeData is the file split into lines
foreach (var row in itemAttributeData)
{
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Although there was a bit more work involved to be able to manipulate the data in the way I wanted, Karthik's suggestion got me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary of strings where the first string references the "properties" name and the second string its characteristic.